# Get Exact Address from LatLong

Tags: google-geocoding-api

I have been trying to get exact address of mobile device using geocode.

Here is my code

```
        function showPosition(position) {
    debugger;
    console.log("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude);
    CLat = position.coords.latitude;
    Clng = position.coords.longitude;
    add = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + CLat + "," + Clng + "&key=" + _globalAPIKey;
    console.log(add);


    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(CLat, Clng);


    if (geocoder) {
        debugger;
        geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latLng }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                debugger;
                console.log(results[0].formatted_address);
                alert('Address:' + results[0].formatted_address);
            }
            else {
                debugger;
                //alert('Geocoding failed: ' + status);
                console.log("Geocoding failed: " + status);
            }
        }); //geocoder.geocode()
    }
}
```

Here I am getting the address but it's not been exact address. Can I specify the boundary or range so that I can get the exact address.
Or I am not getting the accurate LatLog , due to which Address is also wrong.

Kindly provide your suggestion or sample code.

Thanks & Regard
Rahul K Sharma

Comment: Please provide values of CLat, Clng and explain why reverse geocoding is not correct for given coordinate. Typically Google returns the nearest available address. What is happening in your example?

Comment: As Per hardCoding the CLat(19.2005591574) and Clng(72.87131667137147) Value . I get the value as "shop no 27,whispering palm shoppinng centre, Akurli Road, Lokhandwala Twp, Kandivali East, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400101, India" Which is correct .

But When I don't hard code the CLat and Clng then it takes CLat(19.113574399999997) and Clng(72.892416).

That means my latitude & longitude is not be captured correctly..

So how can i get the correct  latitude & longitude?